# jnunemaker-validatable - internationalization option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I am using the [jnunemaker-validatable](https://github.com/jnunemaker/validatable) gem by way of mongomapper, and it seems that the error messages are not coming through mapped to the [standard keys](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) used in Activerecord's i18n file.  I'm not 100% sure that jnunemaker-validatable is the issue here, just seems a likely candidate.  Has anyone used this gem in a multi-lingual way with success?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/ab1a99f472d51847

Short answer appears to be that it's not a feature at this time, but there are various workarounds to get you part of the way there, and a Gem that looks promising: https://github.com/jmonteiro/mongomapper_i18n